# Forwarding cookies with Grafana proxied datasource

Tags: elasticsearch, cookies, proxy, grafana

I'm using a custom Elasticsearch service as the datasource for my Grafana dashboard. An authentication cookie is required to access it, which I want to pass via the Cookie header. In the datasource configuration, I've selected the "proxy" access setting which means that all database requests are proxied through the Grafana service, instead of the browser making the request directly. I've enalbed the "with credentials" setting in order for this to occur. However I can tell by the logs of the custom service that it is not receiving the cookie. Anyone encounter this issue before or have any ideas what might be causing this?